# yii-bootstrap TbButtonGroup: dropdown menu items selector

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I use yii and bootstrap extension for project front-end. In yii-bootstrap documentation I found enough information about widgets api, but I can't realize one issue.. I have code:

```
Yii::app()->controller->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonGroup', array(
    'buttons' => array(
        array( 'label' => '',
               'icon'  => 'tasks',
               'items' => array(
                    array(
                        'label' => 'Setup',
                        'url' => '',
                        /*'class' => '?',*/
                        /*'id' => '?'*/
                    )
               )
        ),
    ),
));
```

I need to execute javascript code when clicking on item of the button in TbButtonGroup. If I specify url for button item element, it will be redirect action. I need to open dialog window instead forwarding user to another page. I prepared code for this logic (using jQuery):

```
$(document).on('click', 'SELECTOR', function (event) {
    // Prevent forwarding user to another page after click on link.
    event.preventDefault();
    // open dialog code...
}
```

Now I need to specify some selector for one of several items in button, which will be generated using TbButtonGroup widget. How can I do this? I need something like that:

```
Yii::app()->controller->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonGroup', array(
    'buttons' => array(
        array( 'label' => '',
               'icon'  => 'tasks',
               'items' => array(
                    array(
                        'label' => 'Setup',
                        'url' => '#',
                        'id' => 'action_setup_btn', // $('#action_setup_btn')
                        'class' => 'action_btn' // $('.action_btn')
                    )
               )
        ),
    ),
));
```

But it's not valid code. How to do it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `linkOptions` parameter for `items`. This is array of attributes which will be added to the link:

```
...
'items' => array(
    array(
       'label' => 'Setup',
       'url' => '#',
       'linkOptions'=>array('class'=>'MyClass', 'id'=>'MyId')
    )
)
...
```

**UPD:**

Also you can use `itemOptions` if you want to add attributes `li` tag:

Comment: Thanks! it works! linkOptions == htmlOptions-for-link? it's true?

Comment: `linkOptions` it list of attributes for `<a>` tag, and `itemOptions` list of attributes for `<li>` tag (which wraps link).